# Haversine Formula in Clojure

Tags: clojure, coordinate-system, geospatial, clojurescript

I implemented the [Haversine formula](https://web.archive.org/web/20171224103604/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51879.html) to calculate the distance between two (latitude, longitude) coordinates.

I was wondering if it looks natural to Clojure programmers.  What could be improved?

```
(ns br.com.reactive-poc.calc)

(def raio 6372.795477598)

(defn calculate-distance
"Calcula distância entre duas coordenadas geográficas"
([source to]
  {:pre [every? (every-pred map? #(contains? % :lgt) #(contains? % :ltd)) [source to]]}
  (let [delta-latitude (Math/toRadians (- (:source/ltd source) (:to/ltd to)))
        delta-longitude (Math/toRadians (- (:source/lgt source) (:to/lgt to)))
        ]
    (* (* raio (* 2 (Math/atan2 (Math/sqrt (+ (Math/pow (Math/sin (/ delta-latitude 2)) 2) 
                                              (* (Math/cos (Math/toRadians (:source/ltd source))) (Math/cos (Math/toRadians (:to/ltd to))) (Math/sin (/ delta-longitude 2)) (Math/sin (/ delta-longitude 2))))) 
                                (Math/sqrt (- 1 (+ (Math/pow (Math/sin (/ delta-latitude 2)) 2) 
                                                   (* (Math/cos (Math/toRadians (:source/ltd source))) (Math/cos (Math/toRadians (:to/ltd to)) ) (Math/sin (/ delta-longitude 2)) (Math/sin (/ delta-longitude 2))))))))) 1000)
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Can you show us an example? The pre-condition seems to be at odds with the way the data is destructured.

Answer (score 5):

### Naming and interface

Please avoid mixing English (`calculate-distance`) with Portuguese (`raio`).  The code should be in English; write your comments in whatever language you prefer.

[`ltd` and `lgt`](http://www.google.com/search?q=ltd+lgt) seem like awkward abbreviations; [`lat` and `lon`](http://www.google.com/search?q=lat+lon) or [`lat` and `lng`](http://www.google.com/search?q=lat+lng) seem more conventional.  The latter is what Google uses for the Maps and Android APIs, for example.

Putting "calculate" in the name of a function seems redundant, especially in a functional programming language.

One of the most surprising behaviours is that your function gives the result in meters, even though your `raio` constant is in kilometers.  To discover that quirk, you would have to scroll all the way to column 219 at the end of the function, at the end of a very long line of code!  A better comment on the function would help; better naming would be beneficial as well.

### Implementation

As I mentioned, those are *very* long lines of code — almost unreadable.  It would be more readable if you broke down the calculation into subexpressions.

In fact, `(+ (Math/pow (Math/sin (/ delta-latitude 2)) 2) (* (Math/cos (Math/toRadians (:source/ltd source))) (Math/cos (Math/toRadians (:to/ltd to))) (Math/sin (/ delta-longitude 2)) (Math/sin (/ delta-longitude 2))))` is a common subexpression that you evaluate twice.  So, not only is your code unreadable, it's also inefficient.

I would convert the latitudes and longitudes to radians right away, since degrees are useless for trigonometry.  Half the difference in angles are easily recognizable quantities.  Defining the \$\sin^2(\theta)\$ function as a lambda is also useful.

```
(def earth-radius-km 6372.795477598)

(defn distance
    "Calcula distância entre duas coordenadas geográficas em metros"
    ([latlng1 latlng2]
        {:pre [every? (every-pred map? #(contains? % :lat) #(contains? % :lng)) [latlng1 latlng2]]}
        (let [lat1 (Math/toRadians (:latlng1/lat latlng1))
              lng1 (Math/toRadians (:latlng1/lng lnglng1))
              lat2 (Math/toRadians (:latlng2/lat latlng2))
              lng2 (Math/toRadians (:latlng2/lng lnglng2))
              half-dlat (/ (- lat2 lat1) 2)
              half-dlng (/ (- lng2 lng1) 2)
              sin2 (fn [x] (Math/pow (Math/sin x) 2))
              a (+ (sin2 half-dlat) (* (Math/cos lat1) (Math/cos lat2) (sin2 half-dlng)))]
             (* 2000 earth-radius-km (Math/atan2 (Math/sqrt a) (Math/sqrt (- 1 a)))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

I happen to have written a distance calculator in Clojure so I am going to show you my code. I'm sorry that it doesn't have answers to all your questions, but I will try to give you some comments, as well. I haven't used `spec`, so I can't say anything about it.

```
(ns mic-project.distance-calculator)

(defn ^:private degree->radian [angle]
  (/ angle 57.2958))

(defn ^:private squared-sine [angle]
  (let [sine (Math/sin angle)]
    (* sine sine)))

(defn ^:private squared-cosine [angle]
  (let [cosine (Math/cos angle)]
    (* cosine cosine)))

(defn distance-km [{:keys [lat-1 lng-1 lat-2 lng-2]}]
  (let [lat-1-rad (degree->radian (Double. lat-1))
        lng-1-rad (degree->radian (Double. lng-1))
        lat-2-rad (degree->radian (Double. lat-2))
        lng-2-rad (degree->radian (Double. lng-2))
        first-squared-sine (squared-sine (/ (- lat-2-rad lat-1-rad) 2))
        second-squared-sine (squared-sine (/ (- lng-2-rad lng-1-rad) 2))
        cosines-product (* (Math/cos lat-1-rad)
                           (Math/cos lat-2-rad))
        square-rooted-sum (Math/sqrt (+ first-squared-sine
                                        (* cosines-product second-squared-sine)))
        earth-radius-km 6371
        haversine-result (* 2 earth-radius-km (Math/asin square-rooted-sum))]
    haversine-result))

(defn distance-miles [coordinates]
  (* 0.621371 (distance-km coordinates)))
```

It is unusual to use `def` inside a function definition. You can `let` `raio`.

I think it's also uncommon to use `let` for defining functions like `delta-latitude` and `delta-longitude`.
I think it's much better to `defn` those functions outside of `calculate-distance`. To make it more obvious that these are helper functions of `calculate-distance`, you could make them `private`.

I suggest you stick to the [Clojure Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide) when you name your vars, so instead of `lgtSource`, use `lgt-source`.

The Clojure Style Guide suggests we use `->` instead of `to` in function names. For example, instead of `convert-to-rad`, I have used the name `degree->radian`.

To make sure you are calling the function with the right type of argument, you can use preconditions. Here's one way to do it. I haven't tested the code below.

```
(defn- valid-longitude? [arg]
  (and
   (number? arg)
   (<= -180 arg 180))

(defn- valid-latitude? [arg]
  (and
   (number? arg)
   (<= -90 arg 90))
```

and then do something like

```
(defn calculate-distance [{:keys [lat-1 lng-1 lat-2 lng-2]}]
  {:pre [(valid-latitude? lat-1)
         (valid-longitude? lng-1)
         (valid-latitude? lat-2)
         (valid-longitude? lat-2)]}
...
...
)
```

To understand `[{:keys [lat-1 lng-1 lat-2 lng-2]}]`, google `Clojure function argument destructuring`.

The function would then be called like this:

```
(calculate-distance {:lat-1 22.664823
                     :lng-1 11.161030
                     :lat-2 32.208499
                     :lng-2 10.741567})
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The pre-condition

- is inoperative
- corrected, is inconsistent with the data shape the function requires.

Let's cut down the function so that it destructures its arguments:

```
(defn calculate-distance
  "Calcula distância entre duas coordenadas geográficas"
  [source to]
  {:pre [every? (every-pred map? #(contains? % :lgt) #(contains? % :ltd)) [source to]]}
  (let [delta-latitude (Math/toRadians (- (:source/ltd source) (:to/ltd to)))
        delta-longitude (Math/toRadians (- (:source/lgt source) (:to/lgt to)))]
    [delta-latitude delta-longitude]))
```

(I've dispensed with the harmless but redundant parentheses wrapping the single arity).

The pre-condition is

```
{:pre [every? (every-pred map? #(contains? % :lgt) #(contains? % :ltd)) [source to]]}
```

This evaluates, in turn,

- `every?`
- `(every-pred map? #(contains? % :lgt) #(contains? % :ltd))`
- `[source to]`

... all of which are logically true - two functions and a vector.

You need to wrap the whole expression in `( ... )` to make it evaluate:

```
{:pre [(every? (every-pred map? #(contains? % :lgt) #(contains? % :ltd)) [source to])]}
```

Before we do that, let's look at the data shape the function requires. For example,

```
(calculate-distance {:source/ltd 0, :source/lgt 0}
                    {:to/ltd 0, :to/lgt 0})
=> [0.0 0.0]
```

The expressions in the `let` use *qualified keywords*: `:source/ltd` ... .

This is bad. We want both points specified with the same shape - the more so since they are symmetrical in effect: the distance from here to there is the same as the distance from there to here.

Let's go with the shape that the (corrected) pre-condition requires:

```
(defn calculate-distance
  "Calcula distância entre duas coordenadas geográficas"
  [source to]
  {:pre [(every? (every-pred map? #(contains? % :lgt) #(contains? % :ltd)) [source to])]}
  (let [delta-latitude (Math/toRadians (- (:ltd source) (:ltd to)))
        delta-longitude (Math/toRadians (- (:lgt source) (:lgt to)))]
    [delta-latitude delta-longitude]))
```

Now

```
(calculate-distance {:source/ltd 0, :source/lgt 0}
                    {:to/ltd 0, :to/lgt 0})
AssertionError ...
```

but

```
(calculate-distance {:ltd 0, :lgt 0}
                    {:ltd 0, :lgt 0})
=> [0.0 0.0]
```

So far, so good.

Let's do a couple of quick examples:

```
(calculate-distance {:ltd 0, :lgt 0}
                    {:ltd 0, :lgt 0})
=> 0.0
```

Good.

```
(calculate-distance {:ltd 0, :lgt 0}
                    {:ltd 0, :lgt 90})
=> 1.0010363727626067E7
```

The distance from the North pole to the equator along the Greenwich meridian is about 10 million metres or 10 thousand kilometres - correct.

---

As for the calculation, I've nothing to add to the other answers. Though I would prefer in a JVM environment to do as you do and call the `Math`functions directly.